# reactjs event listener window.resize

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs and I am trying to do a table exactly like this one in the fiddle using react :
http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/crspu/555/

I created this component :

```
export default class Table extends Component {

    render(){
        return <table className="scroll">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Head 1</th>
                    <th>Head 2</th>
                    <th>Head 3</th>
                    <th>Head 4</th>
                    <th>Head 5</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Content 1</td>
                    <td>Content 2</td>
                    <td>Content 3</td>
                    <td>Content 4</td>
                    <td>Content 5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Content 1</td>
                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
                    <td>Content 3</td>
                    <td>Content 4</td>
                    <td>Content 5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Content 1</td>
                    <td>Content 2</td>
                    <td>Content 3</td>
                    <td>Content 4</td>
                    <td>Content 5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Content 1</td>
                    <td>Content 2</td>
                    <td>Content 3</td>
                    <td>Content 4</td>
                    <td>Content 5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Content 1</td>
                    <td>Content 2</td>
                    <td>Content 3</td>
                    <td>Content 4</td>
                    <td>Content 5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Content 1</td>
                    <td>Content 2</td>
                    <td>Content 3</td>
                    <td>Content 4</td>
                    <td>Content 5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Content 1</td>
                    <td>Content 2</td>
                    <td>Content 3</td>
                    <td>Content 4</td>
                    <td>Content 5</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }

}
```

Can you please help me in handling event listener of resize as shown in the example from jquery to react way ?

Comment: There is nothing about react. Just use plain javascript or jquery to handle window resize event. You can copy code from example you provided.

Comment: how about https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dom-event-listeners.html

Comment: That's plain javascript events.

Answer (score 2):

Just register plain DOM events in `componentWillMount() {}` and remember to unbind them in `componentWIllUnmount() {}`.

Answer (score 2):

This will allow you to watch for resize events:

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.handleResize();
        window.addEventListener('resize',  this.handleResize.bind(this));
}


handleResize() {
           console.log("I've been resized!");
}
```